# Element is not visible. raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

There is the following page.

http://remitly.com/us/en/

You need to select a specific `country` and `click` on it, but when working out the next line, I get an error.

> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

```
select = driver.find_element_by_class_name('f1wrnyr7')
select.click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']")))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best you must scroll to bottom of the page, then click selection country, then click you country want, try this :

```
#scroll to bottom page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
#wait and click country selection, update locator
elmt = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='selectButton_f1lu1q03']")))
elmt.click()
#wait and click you country want
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'md_countryName_fdxiah8') and text()='Colombia']")))
element.click()
```

Comment: Element <span class="sm_countryName_f1n5jsw0">...</span> is not clickable at point (554, 363). Other element would receive the click: <li tabindex="-1" class="f6ttu0a ">...</li>

Answer (score 1):

The exception is raised because the your code is able to find the element in the DOM but the element is not visible on the page. Also, the parent `div` of the `span` contains an attribute called `hidden`. Following is the DOM structure

```
<div hidden="">
<div class="f1g5w0oh">
<div class="rm-container">
<div class="rm-row">
<div class="rm-col-sm-12 order-sm-last">
<div class="f1o6pohl">
<h5 class="foyw123">Send Money To</h5>
<div class="rm-row fywghj7">
<div class="rm-col-md-6 rm-col-lg-4 fhdzg5g">
<div class="rm-col-md-6 rm-col-lg-4 fhdzg5g">
<div class="rm-col-md-6 rm-col-lg-4 fhdzg5g">
<div class="rm-col-md-6 rm-col-lg-4 fhdzg5g">
<div class="rm-col-md-6 rm-col-lg-4 fhdzg5g">
<div class="rm-col-md-6 rm-col-lg-4 fhdzg5g">
<div class="rm-col-md-6 rm-col-lg-4 fhdzg5g">
<div>
<a class="f12qs1j9" href="/us/en/colombia">
<span>
<img class="md_flag_ffypto0" src="https://media.remitly.io/COL_32x21@2x-471f08f81b303eb2d3ac61da0909673f.png" alt="Colombia"/>
<span class="md_countryName_fdxiah8">Colombia</span>
</span>
```

The best way is to reproduce the steps manually and understand that the sequence of steps needed to make the element visible.

Comment: Do you think it will be enough to simply remove the `hidden` attribute?

Comment: It might be possible that the code does it automatically when you perform the steps to find the country manually.

Answer (score 1):

Locators better to use below. To select **to country** dropdown. Sometimes **from country** dropdown comes also selectable, that's why you can find code below to get the lastest dropdown.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

# get all dropdown elements
select_a_countries = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[alt='Open']")))
# filter by visibility
select_a_countries = list(filter(lambda x: x.is_displayed(), select_a_countries))
# we need last one
country_to = select_a_countries[-1]
country_to.click()
# get country we need by alt attribute, should be parameterized 
country = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[alt='Mexico']")
# scroll to and click
# same as JavaScript: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", country)
country.location_once_scrolled_into_view
country.click()
```